# Ember : How to update a single field in an array of JSON objects in a controller?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-cli

How can I update Einstein's score to a 100 in the controller?

In a controller, I have an array of JSON objects like :

```
items = [
         {title:"John", score:24},
         {title:"Einstein", score:2},
         {title:"Mary", score:19}
        ];
```

This is rendered in the template using component like this :

```
{{#each items as |item|}}
  {{some-child-component scoreVal=item.score}}
{{/each}}
```

What should I do to update Einstein's score to a 100? I just want to change that particular field and have it reflect in the app.

I want to avoid replacing the entire array with a new (almost same one), because that causes a refresh for all components in the template.

[FAILED] I tried using :

```
var allItems = this.get('items');
allItems[1]['score'] = 100; //ERROR
```

Also

```
   this.set('items[1][score]',100); //ERROR
```

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the Ember way of doing this:

```
var elem = items.objectAt(1);
Ember.set(elem, 'score', 100);
```

Comment: @kumkanillam
It may. But doing so may omit observers put in place by the framework. Using ember functions like `.objectAt`, `get`, `set`, etc ensures that the required observers fire when the changes are made.

Comment: you are right. but in this case, I guess both are using `Ember.set` since `Ember.set` is also KVO (Key-Value Observing). and I am commenting your answer is for my learning and don't mistake me. thanks :)

Comment: @kumkanillam: No worries. I prefer being on the safer side. Have run into some issues during the initial days of Ember. Debugging it was a pain. I think here, you are 100% correct

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.findBy` to find the record and give it a new value.

If you aren't using Ember Data for your data layer then I would also make the array of objects Ember Objects so you can use `.get` and `.set` to update the attributes.

Here's a [full JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zayehemegu/edit?html,js,console,output) of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly are you trying to set the score to 100?

If you make your items Ember objects

```
items = [
         {title:"John", score:24},
         {title:"Einstein", score:2},
         {title:"Mary", score:19}
        ].map(function(item) { return Ember.Object.create(item) });
```

you will be able to use the setter as `items[1].set('score', 100)`